# Calculating future data based previous data

Tags: statistics

> The sales volume of the next month is predicted by the data in the
>   past.   The sales  volume is changed greatly from month to month, but
>   the annual fluctuation pattern is  almost the same every year.   Which
>   of the following is the most appropriate formula  that can be used for
>   calculating the sales volume of the next month?   Here, Pt+1 is  the
>   sales volume predicted for the next month, St is the sales volume of
>   the current  month t, and the data is retained for three years.

```
a) Pt+1 = (St+ St–1+ St–2) / 3  
b) Pt+1= St xSt / St–1
c) Pt+1= (St+ St–12 + St–24) / 3  
d) Pt+1= (St–11+ St–23+ St–35) / 3
```

I would love to know the right method to solve this one, some explanations will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think it's impossible to decide which model is the best one, on the basis of the information that you give. It may be necessary to look at the annual fluctuation pattern. In general, what you have here is a time series, and there are many good models for time series, depending on the type of series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer d may be the best option, since it calculates the mean of the values observed in the successive month during the previous 3 years. The information that sales volume changes greatly from month to month, but with the same annual fluctuation pattern every year, suggests that a reliable prediction can be based on the same month observed in the previous years.